# Eigenvectors of sum of Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory, spectral-norm

Given two real Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, what can one say about the **eigenvectors** of $A+ \epsilon B$ in relation to $A$? Here $\epsilon \in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon B$ is a slight perturbation.

Comment: Chapter 7 of *Bhatia's Matrix Analysis* has some useful results here

Comment: [Kato](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kato1.pdf#page=90) chapter two.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a result of Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*:

> **Theorem VII.3.2:** *(simplified)* Let $A,B$ be Hermitian operators, and let $S_1,S_2$ be subsets of $\Bbb R$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(S_1,S_2) = \delta > 0$. Let $E = P_A(S_1), F = P_B(S_2)$.  Then if $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the spectral norm (largest singular value), then we have
>   $$
> \|E - F^\perp\| = \|EF\| \leq \frac{\pi}{2\delta}\|A - B\|
> $$

Here, $P_A(S)$ denotes the projection onto the eigenspace of $A$ associated with the elements of $S$, and $\operatorname{dist}(S_1,S_2) = \inf_{x \in S_1, y \in S_2} |x - y|$.  Perhaps this will lead to something useful in your case.